# Service Discovery Eureka Netflix

Tags: java, ruby, spring, microsserviços, soa

eu tenho uma arquitetura SOA com duas `stacks` diferentes uma com java e outra com ruby, tenho um microservice usando spring boot e outro rails, e estou tentando configurar um Service Discovery com Eureka para projetos java especialmente com Spring Boot é muito fácil de se registrar no Service Discovery porém para outra lang sem ser java não achei solução?

**Então é possível registrar no Eureka sem ser um projeto java?** **se sim, como?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a solução:
Você registra seu micro serviço via REST.

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations

Exemplo de json:

```
{
    "instance": {
        "hostName": "rails-checkin",
        "app": "rails-checkin",
        "vipAddress": "com.automationrhapsody.eureka.app",
        "secureVipAddress": "com.automationrhapsody.eureka.app",
        "ipAddr": "127.0.0.1",
        "status": "UP",
        "port": {"$": "3000", "@enabled": "true"},
        "securePort": {"$": "3000", "@enabled": "true"},
        "healthCheckUrl": "http://rails-checkin:3000/checkins",
        "statusPageUrl": "http://rails-checkin:3000/checkins",
        "homePageUrl": "http://rails-checkin:3000/",
        "dataCenterInfo": {
            "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo", 
            "name": "MyOwn"
        }
    }
}
```